# Return entire row and append to value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to write a function that searches a data frame row by row for a values in a column then appends entire row to the right side of the value if that value is found in any row.

```
Dataframe1

Col1 Col2 Col3 Lookup

400  60    80   90

50   90    68   80
```

What I want is a following dataframe:

```
Dataframe 2

Lookup Col1 Col2 Col3

90      50   90   68

80      400  60   80
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The column lookup has the values that I want to search for in columns 1-3. If that value is found in any row then I want to return that entire row and paste it beside that particular value  see Dataframe2.

Comment: Can you explain what condition takes you from df1 to df2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this out;

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,0:-1]
new = pd.DataFrame()
for val in df['Lookup']:
    s = df1[df1.eq(val).any(1)]
    new = new.append(s,ignore_index = True)
new.insert(0,'Lookup',df['Lookup'])
print(new)

#    Lookup  Col1  Col2  Col3
# 0      90    50    90    68
# 1      80   400    60    80
```